# Пример кода TypeScript из спецификации не понятен

Tags: typescript

```
var f: { (): string; }; 
var sameType: () => string = f; // Ok 
var nope: () => number = sameType; // Error: type mismatch
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в этом примере. Взят из спецификации со страницы 13. Может, где-то есть более понятное описание?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первой строчке объявляется переменная *f*, ее тип - функтор, не принимающий аргументов и возвращающий строку.

Во второй строчке объявляется переменная *sameType*, ее тип - функция, не принимающая аргументов и возвращающая строку. Этой переменной присваивают значение, ранее записанное в переменной f.

В третьей строчке объявляется переменная *nope*, ее тип - функция, не принимающая аргументов и возвращающая число. Этой переменной пытаются присвоить значение, ранее записанное в переменной sameType - но не получается, ведь типы этих переменных различны.